# evaluation post-fix with pushing operands into the stack

Tags: scheme

Not sure how to start this off, any suggestions?

Define a SCHEME function, named (eval-postfix p), that will take postfix expression (stored in a list of integers representing operands and characters representing operators), evaluate that expression, and return the result.
Your function should support the operations of addition (#+), subtraction (#-), multiplication (#*), divi- sion(#/), and exponentiation(#\ˆ).
You may want to work incrementally by starting with a function that takes a character representing an operator and can pop two operands off of a stack, evaluate the operator and push the result back on the stack. Next you can add a function that evaluates a postfix expression by pushing operands onto the stack and evaluating operators when encountered. Note, you may want to use the number? function to determine whether an item in the list is an operand or an operator.

Comment: Postfix: `4 5 6 7 + + +` is the same as `(4 + (5 + (6 + 7)))` while `4 5 + 6 + 7 +` is the same as `(((4 + 5) + 6 ) + 7)`. Basically a number is pushed onto the stack and a operator does the action with the top 2 places. eg. `5 3 4 +` will leave `5 7` on the stack. Another `+` and it's `12` on the stack. If you want `((4 * 5) + (6 * 7))` you'll need to do `4 5 * 6 7 * +`

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that executes a single instruction on a stack, and returns the changed stack:

`(define (postfix-execute-one instruction stack)
  ...)`

it should check if instruction is `number?` or a symbol like `'+`. If it's a number you can just return `(cons instruction stack)` to push it, if it's an operator you need to pop 2 items off the stack, add them (or subtract them) and then push that on the stack and return.

Then you can make

`(define (postfix-execute-all instructions stack)
  ...)`

which recursively loops over the list of instructions, executing each one using the helper function defined earlier, until it reaches `null?`. Then it can return the final stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is the suggested starting point from your description spelled out in more detail.
It's a good starting point, so stick to it.

Write a function whose input is one operator and a stack:

```
operator: +
stack: |x y z w|
```

It should pop two operands:

```
operator: +
left operand: x
right operand: y
stack: |z w|
```

evaluate:

```
result: x + y = A
stack: |z w|
```

and return the stack with the result added on top:

```
|A z w|
```

When you're done with that (make sure you test with all five operators) you use this function to implement the full evaluation function.